# Display weather data using the subscription key of open weather

Tags: reactjs, weather

I am trying to add weather to my app, so installed a weather package.

I created subscription key. I followed the exact steps.

But still I am getting the error, can you tell me how to fix it.

Providing my code snippet and sandbox

React package https://github.com/farahat80/react-open-weather#readme

https://codesandbox.io/s/n6ssk7?file=/src/App.js

```
function App() { 
  const { data2, isLoading, errorMessage } = useOpenWeather({
    key: "<key>",
    lat: "48.137154",
    lon: "11.576124",
    lang: "en",
    unit: "metric" // values are (metric, standard, imperial)
  });

  console.log("data2", data2); // undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you are trying to get `data2` from the object returned by the `useOpenWeather` function, when in fact what you have to do is rename it, try this code

```
const { data: data2, isLoading, errorMessage } = useOpenWeather({
     key: "API_KEY",
     lat: "48.137154",
     lon: "11.576124",
     lang: "in",
     unit: "metric" // values are (metric, standard, imperial)
   });
   console.log("data2", data2, isLoading, errorMessage);
```